# Display data from Weight scale using Serial port

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to COM PORT, I want to read data from weight scale and display in a `TextBox`.
I was able to get the data, but it keeps on running (streaming).
I want to show only if changed.

My code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Ports;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int BaudRate = 9600;
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
        foreach (var portName in portNames)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);                  //<-- Adds Ports to combobox
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;                        //<-- Selects first entry (convenience purposes)
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
        if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
        if (_serialPort != null)
            _serialPort.Dispose();
        //<-- End of Block

        _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort
        _serialPort.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen
        textBox1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...\r\n";

    }
    string str ="" ;
    private delegate void Closure();
    private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
            BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
        else
        {
            int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
            int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
            if (nbrDataRead == 0)
                return;
            str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            textBox1.Text = str.ToString();

            //_serialPort.Close(); 
            //var newVal = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
            //if (String.Compare(textBox1.Text, newVal) != 0.0)
            //    textBox1.Text = newVal;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //_serialPort.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember the received data in a variable on class level and check every time when new data arrives if it is different from the one which you remembered (old data) and write it only into the textbox if the data has changed. Depending on what scale you are using, some scales can be configured to only send data if the weight changed.

Comment: That is quite normal for scales.  They normally have a way to configure them so you can explicitly ask for a measurement instead.  Check the manual.  Either way, you are going to have to fix your code.  Don't display the value until you got the *entire* response from the scale.  Using ReadLine() tends to be the correct way to ensure that.  Check the manual.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Com Port Programming, Any sample code will be helpfull. Thankyou.